# How to skip index out of range?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was trying to make learning practice for making an ebay list scrape, my item boxes length 48 but only 26 item has rating div, Im getting `IndexError: list index out of range`, how do I skip this lines or how can I write if item_rating is empty bring "N/A" for example. I tried continue but I couldn't fix. Actually its a general question for this kind of circumstance for different variables like item_shipping,... etc. Thanks in advance.

UPDATED

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

URL='https://www.ebay.com/b/Makeup-Products/31786/bn_1865570' #'https://www.ebay.com/b/Makeup-Products/31786/bn_1865570' #https://www.ebay.com/b/Eye-Makeup/172020/bn_1880663
response=requests.get(URL)
soup= BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
columns=["Name","Price","Rating","Location"]
#Product features
main_table=soup.find('ul',attrs={'class':'b-list__items_nofooter'})
item_boxes=main_table.find_all('div',attrs={'class':'s-item__info clearfix'})
item = item_boxes[0]

df=pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

for item in item_boxes:

    item_name = item.findAll('h3')
    try:
       item_name_row = item_name[0].text.replace('\n','')
    except:
       item_name = "N/A"


    item_price = item.find_all('span',{'class':'s-item__price'})
    try:
       item_price_row = item_price[0].text.replace('\n','')
    except:
       item_price_row = "N/A"      

    try:
       item_rating = item.findAll('div',{'class':'s-item__reviews'})[0].div
       item_rating_row = item_rating.text
    except:
       item_rating_row = None

    try:
       item_location = item_location = item.find_all('span',{'class':'s-item__location s-item__itemLocation'})[0]
       item_location_row = item_location.text
    except:
       item_location_row = None   

    row = [ item_name_row, item_price_row, item_rating_row, item_location_row ]
    df =df.append(pd.Series(row,index=columns),ignore_index=True)
    df.to_csv('ebay1.csv', index=False)


    if item_rating != None:

      row = [item_name[0].text.replace('\n','') for name in item_name] + [item_price[0].text.replace('\n','') for price in item_price] + [item_rating.text.replace('\n','') for rating in item_rating] + [item_location_row[0].replace('\n','') for location in item_location]

    elif item_location != None:

      row = [item_name[0].text.replace('\n','') for name in item_name] + [item_price[0].text.replace('\n','') for price in item_price] + [item_rating.text.replace('\n','') for rating in item_rating] + [item_location_row[0].replace('\n','') for location in item_location]
    else: 
      row = [ item_name[0].text.replace('\n','') for name in item_name] + [item_price[0].text.replace('\n','') for price in item_price] + [item_rating] + [item_location_row]
    df =df.append(pd.Series(row,index=columns),ignore_index=True)

df.to_csv('ebay4.csv', index=False)
```

[image]

Comment: _Im getting IndexError: list index out of range_ Where do you get the error?

Comment: in line item_rating = item.findAll('div',{'class':'s-item__reviews'})[0].div

Comment: What have you tried in order to solve the problem?

Comment: I have tried if not rating or rating.startswith(''): rating='N/A' but this cause error because its before define variable.

Comment: _but this cause error because its before define variable._ Okay, I'm sure you can figure out that one. Have you tried looking at what the result of `item.findAll('div',{'class':'s-item__reviews'})` is? Then `item.findAll('div',{'class':'s-item__reviews'})[0]`?

Comment: Yes the first one is list which contains 0 index and second same extracted one.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by _list which contains 0 index and second same extracted one_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, this get's the listings with None for no rating:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

URL='https://www.ebay.com/b/Makeup-Products/31786/bn_1865570'
response=requests.get(URL)
soup= BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
columns=['name',"price","rating"]
#Product features
main_table=soup.find('ul',attrs={'class':'b-list__items_nofooter'})
item_boxes=main_table.find_all('div',attrs={'class':'s-item__info clearfix'})
item = item_boxes[0]

df=pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

for item in item_boxes:

    item_name = item.findAll('h3')
    item_price = item.find_all('span',{'class':'s-item__price'})
    try:
       item_rating = item.findAll('div',{'class':'s-item__reviews'})[0].div
    except:
       item_rating = None
    if item_rating != None:
      row = [item_name[0].text.replace('\n','') for name in item_name] + [item_price[0].text.replace('\n','') for price in item_price] + [item_rating.text.replace('\n','') for rating in item_rating]
    else: 
      row = [ item_name[0].text.replace('\n','') for name in item_name] + [item_price[0].text.replace('\n','') for price in item_price] + [item_rating]
    df =df.append(pd.Series(row,index=columns),ignore_index=True)

df.to_csv('ebay1.csv', index=False)
```

Here is one i used which is a modification of yours to **scrape** recolorado data for a neighbor hood:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
URL='https://www.recolorado.com/find-real-estate/80817/1-pg/exclusive-dorder/price-dorder/photo-tab/'
response=requests.get(URL)
soup= BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
columns=['address',"price","active","bedrooms","bathrooms","sqft","courtesy"]
#Product features
main_table=soup.find('div',attrs={'class':'page--column', 'data-id':'listing-results'})
item_boxes=main_table.find_all('div',attrs={'class':'listing--information listing--information__photo'})
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

for item in item_boxes:

    price = item.find('li', attrs={'class': 'listing--detail listing--detail__photo listing--detail__price'})
    price_row = price.text.replace('\r','').replace('\n','').replace(' ', '')
    #print(price_row)

    address = item.find('h2', attrs={'class': 'listing--street listing--street__photo'})
    address_row = address.text.replace(', ', '')
    #print(address_row)

    active_listing = item.find('div', attrs={'class': 'listing--status listing--status__photo listing--status__Under Contract'})
    try:
       active_row = active_listing.text
    except:
       active_row = "N/A"
    #print(active_row)

    bedrooms = item.find('li', attrs={'class': 'listing--detail listing--detail__photo listing--detail__bedrooms'})
    try:
       bedrooms_row = bedrooms.text.replace('\r','').replace('\n','').replace(' ', '')
    except:
       bedrooms_row = "N/A"
    #print(bedrooms_row)

    bathrooms = item.find('li', attrs={'class': 'listing--detail listing--detail__photo listig--detail__bathrooms'})
    try:
       bathrooms_row = bathrooms.text.replace('\r','').replace('\n','').replace(' ', '')
    except:
       bathrooms_row = "N/A"
    #print(bathrooms_row)

    sqft = item.find('li', attrs={'class': 'listing--detail listing--detail__photo listing--detail__sqft'})
    try:
       sqft = item.find('li', attrs={'class': 'listing--detail listing--detail__photo listing--detail__sqft'})
       sqft_row = sqft.text.replace('\r','').replace('\n','').replace(' ', '')
    except:
       sqft_row = "N/A"
    #print(sqft_row)

    courtesy = item.find('div', attrs={'class': 'listing--courtesy listing--courtesy__photo show-mobile'})
    try:
       courtesy_row = courtesy.text.replace('\r','').replace('\n','').replace(' ', '')
    except:
       courtesy_row = "N/A"
    #print(courtesy_row)

    row = [ address_row, price_row, active_row, bedrooms_row, bathrooms_row, sqft_row, courtesy_row ]
    df =df.append(pd.Series(row,index=columns),ignore_index=True)

df
#                         address     price          active    bedrooms    bathrooms       sqft                                     courtesy
#0    6920 South US Highway 85-87  $699,000             N/A  5Bedrooms●  4Bathrooms●  3,978Sqft        CourtesyofColdwellBankerResidentialBK
#1               7095 Prado Drive  $414,900  Under Contract  9Bedrooms●  4Bathrooms●  3,000Sqft  CourtesyofKellerWilliamsClientsChoiceRealty
#2          7941 Whistlestop Lane  $399,500             N/A  3Bedrooms●  3Bathrooms●  2,577Sqft           CourtesyofRE/MAXRealEstateGroupInc
#3            7287 Van Wyhe Court  $389,900  Under Contract  4Bedrooms●  3Bathrooms●  2,750Sqft                         CourtesyofPinkRealty
#4   10737 Hidden Prairie Parkway  $369,900  Under Contract  4Bedrooms●  3Bathrooms●  2,761Sqft       CourtesyofKellerWilliamsPartnersRealty
#5            7327 Van Wyhe Court  $362,400             N/A  3Bedrooms●  2Bathrooms●  1,640Sqft                         CourtesyofPinkRealty
#6               7354 Chewy Court  $359,000             N/A  3Bedrooms●  2Bathrooms●  1,680Sqft      CourtesyofRedWhiteAndBlueRealtyGroupInc
#7           238 West Iowa Avenue  $355,000             N/A         N/A  4Bathrooms●  1,440Sqft                        CourtesyofAllenRealty
#8         8181 Wagon Spoke Trail  $350,000  Under Contract  4Bedrooms●  3Bathrooms●  2,848Sqft    CourtesyofKellerWilliamsPremierRealty,LLC
#9                     0 Missouri  $350,000             N/A         N/A          N/A        N/A                 CourtesyofRE/MAXNORTHWESTINC
#10  10817 Hidden Prairie Parkway  $340,000  Under Contract  3Bedrooms●  3Bathrooms●  2,761Sqft       CourtesyofKellerWilliamsPartnersRealty
#11         8244 Campground Drive  $335,000  Under Contract  4Bedrooms●  3Bathrooms●  2,018Sqft                         CourtesyofPinkRealty
```

I'll try re-scraping an ebay site here shortly, if you have another link, pls leave it in the comments and i'll gladly see if i can **scrape** it

UPDATE:

Tried this on another page and it worked

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

URL='https://www.ebay.com/b/Eye-Makeup/172020/bn_1880663' #'https://www.ebay.com/b/Makeup-Products/31786/bn_1865570'
response=requests.get(URL)
soup= BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
columns=['name',"price","rating"]
#Product features
main_table=soup.find('ul',attrs={'class':'b-list__items_nofooter'})
item_boxes=main_table.find_all('div',attrs={'class':'s-item__info clearfix'})
item = item_boxes[0]

df=pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

for item in item_boxes:

    item_name = item.findAll('h3')
    try:
       item_name_row = item_name[0].text.replace('\n','')
    except:
       item_name = "N/A"

    
    item_price = item.find_all('span',{'class':'s-item__price'})
    try:
       item_price_row = item_price[0].text.replace('\n','')
    except:
       item_price_row = "N/A"      
 
    try:
       item_rating = item.findAll('div',{'class':'s-item__reviews'})[0].div
       item_rating_row = item_rating.text
    except:
       item_rating_row = None

    row = [ item_name_row, item_price_row, item_rating_row ]
    df =df.append(pd.Series(row,index=columns),ignore_index=True)
    df.to_csv('ebay1.csv', index=False)


    if item_rating != None:
      row = [item_name[0].text.replace('\n','') for name in item_name] + [item_price[0].text.replace('\n','') for price in item_price] + [item_rating.text.replace('\n','') for rating in item_rating]
    else: 
      row = [ item_name[0].text.replace('\n','') for name in item_name] + [item_price[0].text.replace('\n','') for price in item_price] + [item_rating]
    df =df.append(pd.Series(row,index=columns),ignore_index=True)

df.to_csv('ebay1.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: it worked, thank you so much, I think I can use same method for every item

Comment: Eren, thank you as well, i'm working with Beautiful Soup and learning how to parse, so seeing these questions helps me as well with ideas. I'm trying to extract the spells from the Harry Potter Wiki, so this question gave me a few ideas +1

Comment: Hi again thank you for your help, after that, I've tried to add another item that is item_location, first I tried 'or' and of course it worked wrong so I've never attempt  'and'. Then I wrote another try, except however now I'm having value error, what do you think?

Comment: Eren, i just modified yours so i can scrap another page, i'll post it below they main post,  (give me a few minutes it will show up ) maybe it will give you a few ideas, if not maybe you could ask a new question as i'm working on using BS4 to scrap many real estate data, so i can probably help more with ebay scrapping. I might just retry yours and change my post from the real estate to another ebay scrapping as well as i'm actively working on scrapping

Comment: Eren, i tried another page with the bottom one, and it works, does that help? If not open another question as i think this one is filling up.  And post the link here and i'll definitely have a try at it.

Comment: Hi, the last update was perfectly worked and I just tried to update the script with the 4th item which is item location, I guess I screwed up, lines got duplicate. My aim is to create a 10-20 script for 10-20 major websites like eBay, Amazon, which will be running for direct category links and keyword search links, maybe 2 different script for 2 different url type. I updated my code and output.

Comment: And my next obstacle in my mind, how to jump next url page.